# Dialogflow entity recognition sets a value very different from the ones defined in the console

Tags: dialogflow-es, named-entity-recognition

Dialogflow detects an **ingredients** entity value `'se'` even when `'se'` is not a value defined as valid for **ingredients**.

This is the console parameters for **ingredients** entity.

[image: entity definition]

And this is the `'se'` value that Dialogflow resolves for the required **ingredients** parameter.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to replicate your scenario. what are the training phrases in that intent? What is  the phrase used that produces that result?

Comment: I think its the 'allow automated expansion' tag.

Comment: Can you add to your post both the training phrases, and the parameters in the intent?

Comment: Yes, enabling automated expansion can have that behavior; If you need to have it enabled, remember to add many training phrases an entities that help the agent to correctly detect the entity.

Answer (score 0):

setting off 'allow automated expansion' in the entity configuration solved the problem.